# Some elements gets above the floating bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I am having problem with my floating navigation bar. The folating bar should be above everything but when I scroll through my webpage the form fields and some other elements of the website get above the bar making the bar look untidy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#bt-bar-wrapper{ z-index: 100; }
```